# How to convert this list to a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I'm looping through webpages to grab rows of a table and then append each row to a dataframe. However, I'm getting a list which isn't able to be concatenated into one dataframe. How do I convert this list to allow pd.concat()?

I've tried `pd.DataFrame(data)` but that returns KeyError: 0

Here's the result from print(data) https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ9Nt.jpg:

```
[          Unnamed: 0 2015-2016 2016-2017 2017-2018
0  Average net price    $6,497    $8,311    $7,035,           Unnamed: 0 2015-2016 2016-2017 2017-2018
0  Average net price   $26,916   $27,175   $27,584,           Unnamed: 0 2015-2016 2016-2017 2017-2018
0  Average net price    $8,123    $8,022    $7,687,           Unnamed: 0 2015-2016 2016-2017 2017-2018
0  Average net price         —   $16,694   $21,842,           Unnamed: 0 2015-2016 2016-2017 2017-2018
0  Average net price   $13,888   $12,989   $13,314,           Unnamed: 0 2015-2016 2016-2017 2017-2018
0  Average net price   $28,095   $27,925   $28,406,           Unnamed: 0 2015-2016 2016-2017 2017-2018
0  Average net price    $7,242    $6,960    $8,436,           Unnamed: 0 2015-2016 2016-2017 2017-2018
0  Average net price   $25,839   $26,930   $26,710,           Unnamed: 0 2015-2016 2016-2017 2017-2018
0  Average net price   $18,603   $16,450   $17,145]
```

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

data = []
url = 'https://nces.ed.gov/collegenavigator/?id='
ids = pd.read_excel('ids.xlsx')
for index, row in ids.iterrows():
    try:
        r = requests.get(url+str(row[0]))
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        table = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('table:has(td:contains("Average net price"))')))
        data.append(table[0])
    except:
        pass
print(data)
```

ids are:

```
UnitID
180203
177834
222178
138558
412173
126182
188429
188438
168528
133872
```

Ideally, I'd like the output to have an id column and columns for each year range (2015-2016, 2016-2017, etc) with the net prices filled in the matrix like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqXGx.jpg

Comment: Please provide a sample output based on this input, and edit your input to reflect a valid python list. What you've provided is not valid python.

Comment: Updated my post. I'm guessing the root of my problem is when I'm looping and appending each row as a list, must make it wonky when trying to convert to dataframe later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, just save the id in a separate column of parsed dataframes. Now it is ignored

```
...
for index, row in ids.iterrows(): 
    try: 
        r = requests.get(url+str(row[0])) 
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml') 
        table = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('table:has(td:contains("Average net price"))')), index_col=0)[0] 
        table['id'] = row[0] # save the Id in a separate column
        data.append(table.set_index('id'))
    except: 
        pass

df = pd.concat(data)
```

Result:

```
       2015-2016 2016-2017 2017-2018
id                                  
180203    $6,497    $8,311    $7,035
222178   $26,916   $27,175   $27,584
138558    $8,123    $8,022    $7,687
412173         —   $16,694   $21,842
126182   $13,888   $12,989   $13,314
188429   $28,095   $27,925   $28,406
188438    $7,242    $6,960    $8,436
168528   $25,839   $26,930   $26,710
133872   $18,603   $16,450   $17,145
```

Answer (score 1):

Cool question,

So when you use pandas for anything, it generally gives you a series or dataframe as an output. So when you created a list called `data` and then appended `table[0]` to it. You thought you were appending a list to it (I think). But the `pd.read_html` gives a dataframe. So you just need to create `data` as a Dataframe and then append each dataframe to it.

here's the solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

data = pd.DataFrame()
url = 'https://nces.ed.gov/collegenavigator/?id='
ids = pd.read_excel('ids.xlsx')
for index, row in ids.iterrows():
    try:
        r = requests.get(url+str(row[0]))
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        table = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('table:has(td:contains("Average net price"))')))
        data = data.append(table[0], ignore_index=True)
    except:
        pass
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

data = []
url = 'https://nces.ed.gov/collegenavigator/?id='
ids = pd.read_excel('ids.xlsx')

for index, row in ids.iterrows():

    try:
        r = requests.get(url+str(row[0]))
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        table = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('table:has(td:contains("Average net price"))')))
        dataframe=table[0]
        dataframe.index=row
        data.append(dataframe)
    except:
        pass


df_values= (pd.concat(data,sort=False)
              .drop('Unnamed: 0',axis=1)
              .rename_axis(index='UnitID') )
print(df_values)
```

---

**Output:**

```
        2015-2016 2016-2017 2017-2018
UnitID                              
180203    $6,497    $8,311    $7,035
222178   $26,916   $27,175   $27,584
138558    $8,123    $8,022    $7,687
412173         —   $16,694   $21,842
126182   $13,888   $12,989   $13,314
188429   $28,095   $27,925   $28,406
188438    $7,242    $6,960    $8,436
168528   $25,839   $26,930   $26,710
133872   $18,603   $16,450   $17,145
```